# How to create function that returns mixin function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I try to convert `Polymer.dedupingMixin` ES6 function to TypeScript. I don't sure it's possible or not.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.2/lib/utils/mixin.html

Normally, TypeScript 2.2+ can work correctly for basic mixin function like the following code.

```js
type IConstructable = new (...args: any[]) => object;

function extendClass<T extends IConstructable>(baseClass: T) {
    return class extends baseClass {
        instanceMethod_DynamicClass() { }
        static staticMethod_DynamicClass() { }
    }
}

class Test {
    instanceMethod_TestClass() { }
    static staticMethod_TestClass() { }
}

var d3 = extendClass(Test);
d3.staticMethod_DynamicClass();
d3.staticMethod_TestClass();

var d4 = new d3();
d4.instanceMethod_DynamicClass();
d4.instanceMethod_TestClass();
```

I try to create some function like this declaration fuction.

```js
declare function extendClass<T extends IConstructable>(baseClass: T): {
    new (...args: any[]): {
        instanceMethod_DynamicClass(): void;
    };
    staticMethod_DynamicClass(): void;
} & T;
```

My TypeScript code looks like the following code. It doesn't work correctly. I try modify generic type in many places. But it's still not work.

```js
interface IConstructable<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

function extendClass<T extends IConstructable<T>, TExtended extends IConstructable<TExtended>>(mixin: (base: T) => TExtended & T) {
    return function <T, TExtended>(base: T) {
        return mixin(base);
    };
}

class Test {
    instanceMethod_TestClass() { }
    static staticMethod_TestClass() { }
}

class Test2 {
    instanceMethod_TestClass() { }
    static staticMethod_TestClass() { }
}

var propEffect = extendClass(superClass => {    
    return class internalClass extends superClass {
        instanceMethod_ExtendedClass() { }
        static staticMethod_ExtendedClass() { }
    }
});

var d3 = propEffect(Test) ;
d3.staticMethod_ExtendedClass();
d3.staticMethod_TestClass();

var d4 = new d3();
d4.instanceMethod_ExtendedClass();
d4.instanceMethod_TestClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you need `extendClass()`, since it is essentially the identity function (it takes a mixin as a parameter and returns a mixin with the same behavior), and you could implement it like this with no errors in the rest of the code:

```
function extendClass<M>(mixin: M): M {
  return mixin;
}
```

Assuming you need the signature of `extendClass()` to explicitly indicate that it only accepts mixins, you can do so.  It helps to have a type alias for mixins:

```
type Mixin<X extends IConstructable<{}>> = <T extends IConstructable<{}>>(baseClass: T) => T & X;
```

Read: a `Mixin<ExtendedClassConstructor>` is a function which takes a generic base class constructor and returns something which is both a base class constructor and an `ExtendedClassConstructor`.

Now you can implement `extendClass()` as follows:

```
function extendClass<X extends IConstructable<{}>>(mixin: Mixin<X>): Mixin<X> {
  return mixin;
}
```

Unfortunately, now TypeScript is not clever enough to infer the type of `X` when you call `extendClass()` on the arrow function.  `X` should be `internalClass`, but you can't refer to it since it's not in scope.  You need to define an appropriate type with the same shape as `internalClass`:

```
type InternalClass = {
  new(...args: any[]): {
    instanceMethod_ExtendedClass(): void;
  }
  staticMethod_ExtendedClass(): void;
}
```

and then you can finally call `extendClass()`, being careful to type the arrow function as a mixin:

```
var propEffect = extendClass<InternalClass>(<T extends IConstructable<{}>>(superClass: T) => {
  return class internalClass extends superClass {
    instanceMethod_ExtendedClass() { }
    static staticMethod_ExtendedClass() { }
  }
});
```

This should all work with [no errors](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20IConstructable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20prototype%3A%20T%3B%20%20you%20can%20add%20this%20too%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Mixin%3CX%20extends%20IConstructable%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20IConstructable%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E%28baseClass%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20T%20%26%20X%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20extendClass%3CX%20extends%20IConstructable%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E%28mixin%3A%20Mixin%3CX%3E%29%3A%20Mixin%3CX%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20mixin%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20InternalClass%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20instanceMethod_ExtendedClass%28%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20staticMethod_ExtendedClass%28%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20propEffect%20%3D%20extendClass%3CInternalClass%3E%28%3CT%20extends%20IConstructable%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E%28superClass%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20class%20internalClass%20extends%20superClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20instanceMethod_ExtendedClass%28%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20staticMethod_ExtendedClass%28%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20instanceMethod_TestClass%28%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20static%20staticMethod_TestClass%28%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20d3%20%3D%20propEffect%28Test%29%3B%0D%0Ad3.staticMethod_ExtendedClass%28%29%3B%0D%0Ad3.staticMethod_TestClass%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20d4%20%3D%20new%20d3%28%29%3B%0D%0Ad4.instanceMethod_ExtendedClass%28%29%3B%0D%0Ad4.instanceMethod_TestClass%28%29%3B), although I'm not sure if it's worth it for you.  Hope it helps you make progress.

Comment: Thank for answer. I think your solution almost work. However, I need to write `internalClass` signature twice.

Comment: Yes, I think that might be the best you can do, since you need to refer to an inner class which is not accessible to an outer scope.  If someone else has a better way, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: What's about mixin builder pattern? Is it possible to do in TypeScript? 
class MyClass extends mix(MyBaseClass).with(Mixin1, Mixin2) {  
http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/

Comment: I think current mixin pattern in Polymer 2 looks really ugly. class MyElement extends Mixin1(Mixin2(Mixin3(PolymerElement)))

Comment: Without [variadic kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) it would be hard to type the `with()` function so that it takes an arbitrary number of mixins.  You could probably come up with something well-typed that works like `MixinBuilder.add(Mixin1).add(Mixin2).add(Mixin3).build(MyBaseClass)`, though.